# Python ldap3 how return mail as string (no dict, or list)

Tags: python, ldap3

I need to get all mail address from ldap for a given `cn`...

The issue is when I try to put:

- In a list like: `mylist = [cn, mail]`
- In a dict like: `mydict[cn] = mail`

But I get something like `['cn', mail: a@a.a]` and the result I want is this `[cn, a@a.a]`.

Here's the code:

```
    basedn = config['ldap']['basedn']
    attribs = ['mail']
    data = []
    
    for account in logon_name:
    
        sfilter = f'(cn={account})'
        ldap_conn.search(
            basedn,
            sfilter,
            attributes=attribs
        )
        if ldap_conn.entries:
            test = ldap_conn.entries[0].mail
            data.append([account, test])
            print(test)
            print(data)
```

And the result:

`print(test)`

The **output**:

`aaaaaaa.aaaaaaaaa@aaaaa.aaaa`

When I try to put the variable test value give:

`[['xxxxx', mail: aaaaaaa.aaaaaaaaa@aaaaa.aaaa]]`

I don't know where the mail is provided, and why I don't see it in the test variable and the `print(test)`.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean you don't see in the test, when you just said you saw it when you did print(test)? "and when I try to put the variable test value give:" - no, you're appending a two-element list of account and test (`data.append([account, test])`)

Comment: What is a `cn`? If it's a string you'll always get quotation marks around it. Also if you don't want the `mail` why even bother using a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a simple test environment using the [bitnami openldap image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/openldap/) and the following test data:

```
dn: cn=alice,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: alice
sn: example
mail: alice@example.com

dn: cn=bob,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: bob
sn: example
mail: bob@example.com
```

This lets us attempt to reproduce your issue:

```
>>> import ldap3
>>> ldap_conn = ldap3.Connection('ldap://localhost:1389', 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'secret')
>>> basedn = 'dc=example,dc=com'
>>> attribs = ['mail']
>>> sfilter = f'(cn=alice)'
>>> ldap_conn.open()
>>> ldap_conn.search(basedn, sfilter, attributes=attribs)
True
>>> test = ldap_conn.entries[0].mail
>>> test
mail: alice@example.com
>>>
>>> print(test)
alice@example.com
>>> type(test)
<class 'ldap3.abstract.attribute.Attribute'>
```

So here we see that when you ask for `ldap_conn.entries[0].mail`, you're getting back an `Attribute` object. Let's look at the attributes available on an `Attribute`:

```
>>> dir(test)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__',
'__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__',
'__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__',
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'cursor', 'definition',
'entry', 'key', 'other_names', 'raw_values', 'response',
'value', 'values']
```

The `value` attribute looks promising:

```
>>> test.value
alice@example.com
```

Which suggests you actually want:

```
data.append(test.value)
```

---

Here's a runnable example:

```
import ldap3


ldap_conn = ldap3.Connection(
    "ldap://localhost:1389", "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com", "secret"
)
basedn = "dc=example,dc=com"
attribs = ["mail"]
data = []

for account in ["alice", "bob"]:
    sfilter = f"(cn={account})"
    ldap_conn.open()
    ldap_conn.search(basedn, sfilter, attributes=attribs)
    test = ldap_conn.entries[0].mail
    data.append(test.value)

print(data)
```

Which produces as output:

```
['alice@example.com', 'bob@example.com']
```

Comment: I've placed a slightly extended version of this example [on github](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76825691-ldap-search) that includes the docker compose configuration, sample ldif data, etc.